# Is it practical using cursors when it comes to database auditing (only on SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database, cursor, auditing

I've been researching on SQL Cursors recently and a colleague of mine said that Cursors are best used for auditing. I tried to look for materials over in the internet but no luck.

Can anyone explain why Cursor is good for auditing despite its disadvantages?

Comment: What tasks are you undertaking?  I use cursors for all sorts of things.

Comment: What does only on SQL mean?

Comment: @Goat_CO : I'm trying to do like a presentation regarding cursors

Comment: @DanBracuk : On SQL environment, not oracle or anything

Comment: If you mean SQL *Server*, the product, then please say so. "SQL", by itself, it taken by most people (and the tagging system here on SO) to be the ANSI-Standard SQL *language* that *various* database products support to greater or lesser extents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any task, it's about picking the right tool for the job.  Some disparage the use of cursors due to obviously bad examples of their use, but cursors have their place. They are particularly useful for subsetting data and for reducing code redundancy:

Primarily, I use cursors to perform tasks on subsets of very large datasets, ie, banking data.  With billions of records there are some operations you wouldn't want to do all at once, so looping through by day is a good option.  There are other methods of iterating through subsets, but a cursor performs well at this task, it's still set-based operations, just on smaller sets.

Cursors are also great for looping through multiple tables/fields in a database, no need to re-write a procedure for multiple tables if it's going to be doing the same thing in each table, or if you are consistently working on a variety of databases. For example, I had need to analyze a multitude of various log files generated by multiple systems, but they all had date and ip fields. Trivial to have a cursor loop through each of the tables and combine all relevant data into one spot.

I wouldn't use a cursor to perform row by row actions unless necessary, and while I can't think of a use-case off the top of my head I'm sure they exist.